# Removing a peer/node

Tags: go-ethereum, network, peers

I'm running on a private network at the moment, is there a way to remove a peer from your node without restarting Geth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network#static-nodes)

> Currently the console is lacking support for removing a peer, increasing peercount or adding a non-static peer but not to keep try reconnecting.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind building Geth from source, there's currently an open PR to implement an `admin.removePeer()` command, which would allow you to remove a node from the [static](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network#static-nodes)* node array:

- https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/2740

*It wouldn't allow you to remove nodes from the list of "bootstrap" nodes.

Answer (score 4):

At this time, Geth 1.8.1-stable, is able to do it from the console, with the following command (already mentioned by Richard Horrocks):

```
admin.removePeer('<peer_id>')
```

Also, it is still not [documented](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#list-of-management-apis), but you can use it, without worries.